# Does anyone have a good way of managing Cassandra deployments

Tags: database, deployment, cassandra, azure-pipelines, devops

Does anyone have a good approach for managing cassandra deployments?

The goal here is to have a pipeline for deploying changes to the cassandra tables. When the make up of the table is changed the pipeline will trigger, the DB will be rebuild (if necessary) with Terraform and the changes will be applied.

What I need a solution for is how I control state and how I make sure that my pipeline can be run to rebuild the databases without having to run CREATE scripts and then apply ALTER scripts that build up over-time as we make changes.

In my team we're building up a backlog of alter scripts, and it makes me feel uncomfortable...

Right now, I don't see much in the way of tools, guidance or documentation for doing this.

I'm using Terraform, Aiven Cassandra and Azure pipelines for all this, but it's a bit like taking a wild stab in the dark with all these configurations. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does no one have an answer to this one?